# Image upload not retrieving $_GET from form

Tags: php

I have a problem with uploading image paths to my database. I have a page `tutorLanding.php` with a file upload form to allow users to change their profile image.

**tutorLanding.php**

```
               <div class='upload-form'>
                       <form action='changeProfile.php?studentNumber='$studentID' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                       Change Profile Image:
                       <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>
                       <input type='submit' value='Upload Image' name='submit'>
                       <br>                      
                      </form>                     
                      </div>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<div class = 'imageWrapper'>
                        <img src = '/img/avatar/defaultAvatar.png' alt = 'your image'/>
                        </div>";
                }
```

I am attempting to pass a $_GET from:

`<form action='changeProfile.php?studentNumber='$studentID' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

so I can assign a new profile picture to the unique student in my database.

However, this isnt working at all when I get to `changeProfile.php`. No file path is moved into the database and no image is moved to my folder. I have all PHP errors enabled but yet I am only getting `undefined index: studentID` which makes me believe the `$_GET` is this issue. Even when I hardcode the value '40061947' (User 1) as `$studentID` still doesn't pass through.

**What am I missing here?**

**changeProfile.php**

```
$studentID = $_GET['studentNumber'];
$userQuery = "SELECT * from users WHERE studentNumber = '$studentID'";
$resultQuery = (mysqli_query($conn, $userQuery));


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $maxsize = 2097152;
    $format = array('image/jpeg');

    if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] >= $maxsize) {
        $error_1 = 'File Size too large';
        echo '<script>alert("' . $error_1 . '")</script>';
    } elseif ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] == 0) {
        $error_2 = 'Invalid File';
        echo '<script>alert("' . $error_2 . '")</script>';
    } elseif (!in_array($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'], $format)) {
        $error_3 = 'Format Not Supported. Only .jpeg files are accepted';
        echo '<script>alert("' . $error_3 . '")</script>';
    } else {

        $target = 'img/profile_images';
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        $fileTarget = $target . $fileName;
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName, $fileTarget);


        if ($result) {
            echo "Your file <html><b><i>" . $fileName . "</i></b></html> has been successfully uploaded";
            $insertPath = "INSERT INTO users (imagePath) VALUES ('$fileName') WHERE studentNumber ='$studentID'";
            echo "$studentID";
            $resultQuery = (mysqli_query($conn, $insertPath));
        } else {
            echo "Sorry !!! There was an error in uploading your file";
        }
    }
```

I have attached screenshots to show you exactly what is happening. Thanks for any advice! [image: Undefined Index Error]

Comment: `$insertPath = "INSERT INTO users (imagePath) VALUES ('$fileName') WHERE studentNumber ='$studentID'";` should this not be update instead of insert? As you are already trying to pull the user info from the database table users so a instance of the user already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$insertPath = "INSERT INTO users (imagePath) VALUES ('$fileName') WHERE studentNumber ='$studentID'";` should this not be update instead of insert? As you are already trying to pull the user info from the database table users so a instance of the user already exists?
Try changing that code to
`$insertPath = "UPDATE users SET imagePath = '".$filename."' WHERE studentNumber = '".$studentID."'");`

Comment: yes, an update is what I should have been doing! Worked like a charm once I got the ````$studentID```` passed through. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have closing quotes in form declaration:

```
<form action='changeProfile.php?studentNumber='$studentID' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

AS you can see your form action does not include your $studentID. Try to change it to

```
<form action="changeProfile.php?studentNumber={$studentID}" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: Thanks @myxobek, that worked pefect, could not understand why is wasn't getting sent. So simple. Much appreciated!